# Can't change span on hover of <a> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the #triangle-left <`span`> change background-color to match <`a`> when any of the anchors are hovered over. I've tried referencing the id and the actual span element. I've also tried the addClass (which is currently written in) and using the css selector to change border-top-color.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').hover(function(){
      $("#triangle-left").addClass("changed");
    }, function(){
      $("#triangle-left").addClass("normal");
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #499;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }

nav ul a:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
  }

.changed {
  border-top-color: darkgray;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.normal {
  border-top-color: #444;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

@media all and (max-width: 799px){
  nav ul {
    height: 160px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 919px){
  nav ul {
    width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
  
  #triangle-left, triangle-right {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 920px){
  nav ul {
    width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
  
  #triangle-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 460px);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border-top: 40px solid #444;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  }

  #triangle-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: calc(50% - 460px);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border-top: 40px solid #444;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <span id="triangle-left"></span>
  <ul>
    <a href="#" class="text-center one"><li>HOME</li></a>
    <a href="#" class="text-center two"><li>PROJECTS</li></a>
    <a href="#" class="text-center one"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
    <a href="#" class="text-center two"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
  </ul>
  <span id="triangle-right"></span>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/scevans3452/pen/OgdEyx

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do as the `#triangle` elements are invisible. Also note that your HTML is invalid as the `li` elements *must* be children of the `ul`. Move the `a` inside the `li` instead

Comment: Important note: For anyone testing this, **maximize the snippet**. The triangle edges don't show unless the res is bigger than `920px`, as per the media query.

Comment: I have the <li> wrapped in the <a> because I wanted the whole 'block' the be selected when hovered over. I'm in the process of learning, so I was unaware that my code is invalid. The #triangle elements are supposed to be visible while the window is larger than 920px and hidden otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to achive what you want is changing css via jquery:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $("#triangle-left").css('border-top-color', 'darkgray');
}, function() {
    $("#triangle-left").css('border-top-color', '#444');
});
```

Your current javascript is wrong aswell. You are adding both classes to the element. By doing that you add or override ones properties.

If you want to use your current code you should for example make only one class which toggles on hover(is added mousein and removed mouseout).

Comment: I had tried to implement this initially, but I must have gotten some syntax wrong. When referencing <a>, does it have to be in single quotes? Thank you for the help!

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The classes are indeed added properly, there is nothing wrong with your Javascript code. The problem is that to display a border, you also need to specify the `border-width` and the `border-style` properties like so:

```
.changed {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: darkgray;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.normal {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #444;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is your code, fixed: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJxmOX

Answer (score 1):

You're never *removing* the classes, only adding them. At any point, your triangles will either be `changed`, or `changed normal`.

Additionally, your `.changed` and `.normal` selectors are [not as specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as your `#triangle-left` and `#triangle-right` selectors, therefore they will be ignored.

That being said, we really don't need the `.normal` class - we can just add/remove the `changed` to indicate the color. We just have to make it a bit more specific:

```
#triangle-left.changed, #triangle-right.changed {
    ...
}
```

I've slightly re-factored the code to avoid duplicate lines of code (by using a single function as both the `hover` and `blur`), and made use of [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of adding/removing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').hover(toggleHover, toggleHover);
});

function toggleHover() {
    $("#triangle-left").toggleClass("changed");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #499;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }

nav ul a:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
  }

#triangle-left.changed, triangle-right.changed {
  border-top-color: darkgray;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.normal {
  border-top-color: #444;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

@media all and (max-width: 799px){
  nav ul {
    height: 160px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 919px){
  nav ul {
    width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
  
  #triangle-left, triangle-right {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 920px){
  nav ul {
    width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  nav ul a {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -.5%;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
  
  #triangle-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 460px);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border-top: 40px solid #444;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  }

  #triangle-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: calc(50% - 460px);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border-top: 40px solid #444;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <span id="triangle-left"></span>
  <ul>
    <a href="#" class="text-center one"><li>HOME</li></a>
    <a href="#" class="text-center two"><li>PROJECTS</li></a>
    <a href="#" class="text-center one"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
    <a href="#" class="text-center two"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
  </ul>
  <span id="triangle-right"></span>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your span has no size
2. You're adding classes but not removing them so you end up with collisions